# <uses-permission> vs android:permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

What's the difference between:

```
<uses-permission android:name="some_permission" />
```

and

```
<activity android:permission="some_permission" />
```

My application uses the former but not the latter and still works. Why would I use the latter? **Specifically, why does it work without the latter?**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is clear from the structure and tags itself i.e. `uses-permission` means this permission will be used by the app and `android:permission` **inside** activity tag means permission required to start that activity.
Below is difference between `uses-permission` and `android:permission` from official documentation.

`android:permission` (**Activity permission enforcement**)

> Permissions applied using the
>   android:permission attribute to the  tag in the manifest
>   restrict who can start that Activity. The permission is checked during
>   Context.startActivity() and Activity.startActivityForResult(). If the
>   caller doesn't have the required permission then SecurityException is
>   thrown from the call.

Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#permission_enforcement

`uses-permission`

> Specifies a system permission that the user must grant in order for
>   the app to operate correctly. Permissions are granted by the user when
>   the application is installed (on devices running Android 5.1 and
>   lower) or while the app is running (on devices running Android 6.0 and
>   higher).

Link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Now come to **your question**:

> My application uses the former but not the latter and still works. Why
>   would I use the latter? Specifically, why does it work without the
>   latter?

**Answer**: as from above explanation it is clear that latter is required if you want some other app to access your that activity i.e. that permission is not required by your app or activity But other apps to start that activity. So your app will work perfectly fine without latter one i.e. `android:permission`

Hope it make sense.

Comment: @Barry, did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you, and I upvoted it. However I selected @alijandro as the correct answer because he posted first (and also answered correctly).

Comment: @BarryFruitman   Check the timestamp, I posted one hour before that answer and also I explained in details (in stackoverflow it is highly recommended to post a detailed answer). My answer is also correct. Lastly, after whole explanation I specifically answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `<uses-permission>` is when your application is seeking the user's permission to use some feature

   Ex:

> ```
> <uses-permission
>      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>      android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
> ```

2. `<permission>` is when your application is requiring other apps to seek the user's permission to use some feature of yours.

   Ex:

> ```
> <permission android:description="string resource"
>             android:icon="drawable resource"
>             android:label="string resource"
>             android:name="string"
>             android:permissionGroup="string"
>             android:protectionLevel=["normal" | "dangerous" |
>                                      "signature" | ...] />
> ```

You can read :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: any example of this like when to use or what will be the use case for <permission>

Answer (score 1):

In summary,

`<uses-permission android:name="some_permission" />` is something your app should hold to perform some user data sensitive or dangerous operation.

`<activity android:permission="some_permission" />` is something other apps or other component in your app should hold in order to start your activity.